# nginx cause ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when using variable set $upstream

Tags: nginx

I do have a very odd phenomenon when configuring nginx as reverse proxy.
While the following works just fine

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://host:8443/;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
}
```

The next lines of code causing redirection problems (and browser response with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

```
location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.11;
    set $us https://buerger:8443/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass $us;
    proxy_ssl_verify off;
}
```

The reason why I was trying to setup that way using a variable as upstream, is to silently continue the startup of nginx, even when the host is unavailable at startup.

Im using nginx 1.21.6 as docker container

Comment: Show full config. Do you have a http -> https redirect? Put `resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;` from `location` to `server`-block. Put just `buerger:8443` into variable and `proxy_pass https://$us`

Comment: One of the reasons can be different behavior of the implicit `proxy_redirect default` directive (see the [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)). Usual way of debugging this is using some tools like `curl` to check the actual `Location` HTTP header value returned by the upstream comparing with those returned by nginx itself, but I have a very limited docker knowledge and cannot advice you further.

Comment: However you can define your own custom log format and log the `$upstream_http_location` and `$sent_http_location` variables for both cases (working and non-working ones), providing such an information can be helpful to track down the issue.